# Getting values from postman x-www-form-urlencoded to flask-restful

Tags: api, flask, postman, flask-restful

In raw posting, I can get the values of JSON with this below:

```
[
    {
        "username": "paul",
        "password": "paul1"
    },
    {
        "username": "paul2",
        "password": "paul12"
    },
    {
        "username": "paul3",
        "password": "paul14"
    }
]
```

And my flask code:

```
class CreateUser(Resource):

    def post(self):
        try: 

            conn = None
            json_dict = request.get_json(force=True, silent=True)
            x = len(json_dict)

            name = str(json_dict[0]['username'])


            print(x)
            return name
        except Exception as e:
            x = str(e)
            x.replace('\n', '')
            return {'status' : 'failed', 'message' : str(x)}
        finally:
           if conn is not None:
               conn.close()
```

How can I make a POST request in postman with `x-www-form-urlencoded` selected? I'm getting an error in postman. Also, what code can you suggest to get multiple values in json with `x-www-form-urlencoded` selected? thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: as I see you are processing data as `json`, but not as `form`. why you can't just send `json` string from postman?

Comment: because our mobile dev has needed the bulk form. in my side as back end, i dont even care about it but in their side i just need to cooperate as we are one team in our current project.

Comment: don't understand. are you trying processing `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as `application/json`?

Comment: I don't understand what do you want ? What is that JSON ? Are you sending it in a POST request ? From your code, when I run it, If I send JSON as `application/json`, I get proper response, that is `paul`.

Comment: @danila Ganchar. I'm asking what is the way of application/x-www-form-urlencoded. im sorry if my question is complicated. i am new in flask python. can you help me to get multiple data in just 1 key?

Comment: I can't understand because I don't know what you need))). do you just need to send json to server?